# how to pass query strings in urls.py with ?key=value& in django

Tags: python, angularjs, django, query-string, django-urls

In the django docs it is noted that:

> Now in your time on the web you may have come across such beauties as “ME2/Sites/dirmod.asp?sid=&type=gen&mod=Core+Pages&gid=A6CD4967199A42D9B65B1B”. You will be pleased to know that Django allows us much more elegant URL patterns than that.

However, I am trying to pass through query strings with this pattern in mind. How might one go about passing key=value pairs as so inside of django's urls.py

Also note that this is for project using Angular and Django together.

currently my angular patterns are coming out in query string
I.E. http://localhost/data/?key1=value1&key2=value2

If you have any further detail on how to handle $http.post, I will take in any advice.

UPDATE:

Here is my VIEWS.PY

```
#THREE PARAMETERS: storyElementName, facet, variants(can be multiple)
def storyElements_getOrCreate(request, storyElementName, facet, variants):
contData = lsContinuityData.ContinuityData()
if request.method == "POST":
    storyElementName = request.POST.get("storyElementName")
    facet = request.POST.get("facet")
    for key in request.POST:
        variants = request.POST.getlist("variants")
    storyElement = contData.storyElement(storyElementName, facet=facet, variants=variants)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(storyElementName, facet, variants), content_type="application/json")
else:
    storyElementGroups = contData.getStoryElements()
    if len(storyElementGroups):
        storyElements = [storyElement.toJSON() for storyElement in storyElementGroups]
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(storyElements), content_type="application/json")
```

here is my angular controller

```
function addStoryElement(storyElementName, facet, variants){
    seParams = {storyElementName: vm.storyElementName, facet: vm.facet, variants: vm.variants}
    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/lsContinuity/storyelements/',
        method: "POST",
        params: seParams
    })
```

Hopefully this is a bit more helpful. I am passing multiple parameters, however, I might be doing this wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about, the start of your question is about get parameters and then your code relates to post data, what is the actual question you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on any defined URL.

So, in your view corresponding to `http://localhost/data/`, let's say `DataView` (assuming CBV):

```
class DataView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # To get key=value params
        params = request.GET  # This should return a dict {'key': 'value'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what would be preferable and more in the spirit of Django, would be for your urls to possess this pattern in your `urls.py`.

```
url(r'^data/?P<val1>\d+/?P<val2>\d+$', 'Project.views.my_project.page', name="my_project")
```

Then you can retrieve the values in your view, something like this

```
def page(request, val1, val2):
    record1 = MyModel.objects.get(key1=val1)
    record2 = MyModel.objects.get(key2=val2)

    ...
```

`d+` receives one or more decimal digits.

Your url will then have the passed values like so

```
http://localhost/data/val1/val2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have realized what was wrong.

When sending data from AngularJs using $http's POST, it sends the data with the content-type = "application/json" to the server. Django didn't understand that format.

Solution is to change the content-type header by using following config:

```
    app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';}]);
```